# New context menu action not displayed

Tags: windows, contextmenu, file-association

I've configured the .avi file format, so that a new action should appear in the context menu. My problem is, that the entry won't show up...

What am I doing wrong?

Here is what I've configured:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.avi --> Default value: avi-file
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\avi-file\shell\newcommand\command --> Value: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "%1"
```

Answer (score 0):

The default ProgId for .avi used to be `AVIFile` (not `avi-file`) but you are supposed to programmatically look it up on the machine. On my machine the .avi ProgId is `WMP11.AssocFile.AVI`. The ProgId can also change when another program is set as the default program for that file type.

On Windows XP and later you can register secondary commands based on the file extension without having to worry about the ProgId by using the [SystemFileAssociations key](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872121(v=vs.85).aspx#reg_verbs).

Try registering your new command under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SystemFileAssociations\.avi\shell\newcommand\command`